# discord.js argument startsWith must not be a regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, discord, discord.js

[image]

Why does this not work? I need it to find if it starts with a number, and to take it even further, I need it to do this with multiple numbers. For example, if it starts with 1259823 it will do this code. I imagine it's probably because a lot of things can fall in this category, but is there any workaround?
Edit: it throws an error because `startsWith` must not be a regular expression.
Workaround is using .test();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#startsWith` only accepts a string argument. You can use `^` anchor to match the start of the string and use `RegExp#test` to verify the input.

```
if(/^[0-9]/.test(msg.content)){
   //...
}
```

Comment: @Issayah This is what regular expressions are meant to be used for; `String#startsWith` was not intended to be used for this purpose.